# Hidden spoilers too high

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, spoilers

On the mobile iOS app for Stack Exchange, spoilers have empty space (depends on the lines of the hidden text) that fill up the quote box.

For example:

[image: Spoiler versus. Quote]

The `???` is a block quote (taking up on line) and the `Spoiler` takes up two, as the hidden text is one line.

This can be easily solved by making the spoiler box one line, and a smooth drop-like animation can occur to open it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.5.0.2.

Paragraphs in posts normally have a 1 line margin below them.  When they're in quotes, however, this creates a huge blank area at the bottom of the document, so we correct it with the following style which sets the last paragraph's margin to zero:

```
blockquote p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Or rather, it sets the margins of the last item in the quote to zero *iff* that item is a paragraph.  When we inserted the "Spoiler" link into the quote, it became the last element and the paragraph's style reverted causing an extra large margin.

Now I'm inserting the link as the first element so it shouldn't break the styling.

You can try this change when it's built by [becoming a beta tester](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/forms/d/18ZDfsBm35cV72Gzf88zPaMLQwrSRPwP2__RnPb-uqTs/viewform).

Comment: I'm definitely signing up. Is it TestFlight?